# How to set a page layout to a different master page?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, master-pages

If there are two master pages on a site. How can I set a second set of page layouts to draw from the second master page rather than the default master page for the site?

I've seen the MasterPageFile="" suggestion, however, I received a file not found, although the path/file exists (~/_catalogs/masterpage/MyMaster.master).

Secondly, is it possible to do this purely through SharePoint Designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The master page resides in the gallery at the site collection level.

So, you should modify the `MasterPageFile` attribute as below:

```
<%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="/_catalogs/masterpage/custom2.master"
```

or using the `~` operator as below:

```
<%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/custom2.master"
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the ~sitecollection/ path worked. Although I tried /_catalogs.. too, but that didn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Master Page in the `Page_PreInit` method.

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.MasterPageFile = "~/Site1.Master";
}
```

Comment: would this be in the page layout itself?

Comment: No, this would be in the code behind file of the page.